# jQuery slider tutorials?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Does anyone know of some good tutorials that explain how to use the JQuery Slider.

I've found a few, but none of them really present what I need in clear terms.  What I really need to figure out how to do is make the slider go from 1.0 - 5.0 (including all tenths) and when it changes set a hidden control based on that value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation on the jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider/slider#options) is pretty good.

```
$('#mySlider').slider({
    min : 1,
    max : 5,
    stepping: .1,   // or, steps: 40
    change : function (e, ui) {
        $('#myHiddenInput').val(ui.value);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just found that code a minute ago, and it seems to do what I need, but for some reason it's not passing the tenths value, just the whole number.

It looks like the slide has the right number of click though.  Any ideas?

Comment: you could fudge it and set min: 10, max: 50, stepping: 1, ... .val(ui.value / 10)

Answer (score 1):

I have written an article on using the jQuery UI Slider at my website, check out the link:

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/using-the-jquery-ui-slider/

Thanks and let me know if you have any questions,
Ryan