# JQuery Slider not passing tenths value

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a JQuery slider that's working pretty well, but for some reason it's not passing the tenths value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#scoreSlider").slider({
            'steps': 40,
            'min': 1.0, 
            'max': 5.0,
            'startValue': 3, 
            'slide': function(e, ui){ 
                document.getElementById('div_score').innerHTML = ui.value;
            }
        });        
});
```

It appears that there are the right number of clicks on the slider, but the passed value only has the whole number.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider/slider#options),

> ui.value: **Integer** - the current handle's value

Why don't you change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scoreSlider").slider({
            'steps': 40,
            'min': 10, 
            'max': 50,
            'startValue': 30, 
            'slide': function(e, ui){ 
                    document.getElementById('div_score').innerHTML = ui.value/10.0;
            }
    });        
});
```

It seems to produce the decimal values that you desire.

Comment: I see that you already received this answer in the other question you asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297245/jquery-slider-tutorials

Comment: Ya, thanks.  I intended to update this question with the correct answer, but I got pulled into the code.  Thanks for the help.